# Laravel pagination как изменить количество ссылок?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Стандартный вывод пагинации в ларавелл предусматривает вывод 11 ссылок для навигации:

```
<< 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 21 22 >>
```

Как изменить их количество например на 5?

```
<< 1 2 ... 21 22 >>
```

Comment: Сделайте свой шаблон пагинатора, не?

Comment: Вы правы [ссылка](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=57442#p57442)

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сделал свой шаблон [пример](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=57442#p57442)

Answer (score 1):

$news->onEachSide(0)->links()

Comment: Стоить размещать более развернутые ответы